# Do I need this field in GROUP BY to not show duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a query below where a it retrieves data depending on the term(s) the user entered in the a search bar. Now what I am trying to do is not display duplicate data, so if there are 2 rows where all the fields are exactly the same, then it is a duplicate row, so it only shows this row once not multiple times. Now I think it seems to do this as I see no duplicate rows but all I did was do a GROUP BY with all the SELECT fields except for the Answer field as it doesn't let me have a group concat in the GROUP BY clause.

But what my question is that do I need that field  in the GROUP Y clause to not show duplicate rows or is it not really needed?

```
SELECT
      q.QuestionContent, 
      o.OptionType, 
      q.NoofAnswers, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',') AS Answer, 
      r.ReplyType, 
      q.QuestionMarks
    FROM Question q
    LEFT JOIN Answer an
      ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
    LEFT JOIN Reply r 
      ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
    LEFT JOIN Option_Table o 
      ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
    WHERE ".implode(" AND ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "q.QuestionContent LIKE ?"))."
    GROUP BY   q.QuestionContent, 
      o.OptionType, 
      q.NoofAnswers, 
      r.ReplyType, 
      q.QuestionMarks
    ORDER BY ".implode(", ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ?, 1, 0) DESC"))."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need the `group_concat()` in the `select`.  The `group by` will ensure that any particular combination of values will appear once for the columns in the `group by`.  Because these are guaranteed to be distinct, you don't have to worry about any other columns.

The `group_concat()` is a calculated column, based on the summaries.  You are not permitted to have such columns in a `group by` statement.  If you want to aggregate on them again, then you need to use a subquery.

Comment: So you are saying either group_concat in SELECT and not include that field in Group By OR other way round, don't include group concat in select field for answer, but include answer in group by? So if this is correct then my query is fine doing what it is suppose to do which is not show duplicate results?

Comment: @user1914374 . . . You cannot put functions like `min()`, `max()`, `avg()`, and `group_concat()` in the `group by` clause.  If you wanted to group by them, you would need a subquery.  So, yes, your query is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would think [`DISTINCT`](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL) might work better/be simpler:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT q.QuestionContent,
```

Comment: This is very much not the right answer.  The query is clearly doing an aggregation because of the `group_concat()` function call.